# How to implement a simple reply in rebus

Tags: rebus

```
public static void SendREsbDx(Job job)
{
    using (var adapter = new BuiltinContainerAdapter())
    {
        adapter.Handle<ReplyMsg>(msg =>
        {
            string mss = msg.message;
        });

        Configure.With(adapter)
            .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(LogLevel.Warn))
            .MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
            .Transport(t => t.UseSqlServer("server=.;initial catalog=rebus_test;integrated security=true","consumerx","error")
                             .EnsureTableIsCreated())
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
        adapter.Bus.Send<Job>(job);
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to send a message to a consumer. The consumer will use the bus.Reply, but the above code obviously does not work.

I simply want to be able to receive a reply from the consumer. How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your consumer does not have a handler for `Job` messages.

In your case, it sounds like you'll need two bus instances - a *consumer instance* that has an implementation of `IHandleMessages<Job>` which will `bus.Reply(new ReplyMsg {...})`, and a *producer instance* that has an implementation of `IHandleMessages<ReplyMsg>` which will `bus.Send(new Job{...})` and do whatever needs to be done in the reply handler.

If you're interested in looking at some sample code that demonstrates request/reply, take a look at [the integration sample](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/Integration) in [the Rebus samples repository](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples) which has some simple request/reply going on between the Client (which would correspond to the producer in your case) and the IntegrationService (which corresponds to the consumer).

The following code snippet demonstrates how it can be done:

```
var producer = new BuiltinContainerAdapter();
var consumer = new BuiltinContainerAdapter();

consumer.Handle<Job>(job => {
    ...
    consumer.Bus.Reply(new ReplyMsg {...});
});

producer.Handle<ReplyMsg>(reply => {
    ....
});

Configure.With(producer)
     .Transport(t => t.UseSqlServer(connectionString, "producer.input", "error")
                      .EnsureTableIsCreated())
     .MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
     .CreateBus()
     .Start();

Configure.With(consumer)
     .Transport(t => t.UseSqlServer(connectionString, "consumer.input", "error")
                      .EnsureTableIsCreated())
     .MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
     .CreateBus()
     .Start();

// for the duration of the lifetime of your application
producer.Bus.Send(new Job {...});


// when your application shuts down:
consumer.Dispose();
producer.Dispose();
```

and in your app.config there must be an endpoint mapping that maps `Job` to `consumer.input`:

```
<rebus>
    <endpoints>
         <add messages="SomeNamespace.Job, SomeAssembly" endpoint="consumer.input"/>
    </endpoints>
</rebus>
```

I hope you can see now why your code does not work. Please let me know if I should elaborate further :)

I've added a [request/reply sample](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/RequestReply) to [the Rebus samples repository](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples) to serve as proof that the code shown above can actually run (provided that you remove the `....` etc of course - you need a basic understanding of C# to be able to use this code)

Comment: Good information, but let me repeat the question a bit differently. I'm interested in HOW to implement the reply! When I do this it complains that it could not find any handlers to execute a message of that type. That's the part I'm missing and I don't see any simple examples, so I assume I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I just noticed something odd. If I change to UseSqlServerInOneWayClientMode, it does produce the message in the database instead of an error. The code is exactly the same, except it's one way and the endpoint is specified in web.config.

Comment: That sample is attempting to show other features(Windsor container, etc.) that obfuscates the simple thing I need to know, which is how to declare and register a handler in the producer. Just out of curiosity, is this a rarely used feature, and is there another pattern I should be using if I need an immediate response from the consumer?

Comment: Something is really off! Forget the consumer, the producer always produces an error(in the database) when I use "UseSqlServer" and there is no handler for the Job type, but if I have the handler, it eats the message, why is that?

Comment: Rebus.UnhandledMessageException: Could not find any handlers to execute message of type Messages.Job
  at Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.Dispatch[TMessage](TMessage message)
  at Rebus.Bus.Worker.DispatchGeneric[T](T message)   at Rebus.Bus.Worker.DoTry()

Comment: The error is an indication that the consumer does not have a handler for `Job`. If I understand your setup correctly, you have a _producer_ that will `bus.Send(Job)` to a _consumer_, which will `bus.Reply(ReplyMsg)` back to the _producer_, which means that the consumer's adapter must have `.Handle<Job>(job => {...})` called, and the producer's adapter must have `.Handle<ReplyMsg>(reply => {...})` called

Comment: Correct, but that's in the code I've shown originally, that doesn't work! Besides, the consumer isn't in issue right now, as I said before, you don't need a consumer to send a message, and the error is coming from the producer. Wouldn't it be simpler to just show the code of how to do this, isn't it just a few lines?

Comment: That code has a LOT of problems, starting with it's not possible to have the transport first and then go to MessageOwnership. I simply don't think you're hearing me. There's nothing wrong with the code because it WORKS if I use "UseSqlServerInOneWayClientMode", and ALL I'm trying to do is add a reply! This shouldn't be this hard, I simply need a return from the consumer, why can't you show an example that is actually tested. I'll ask again! Is this NOT the way to get a reply from a consumer or is there another way?

Comment: "(...) it's not possible to have the transport first and then go to MessageOwnership." - What led you to believe that?

I hear you - I'm actually trying to help you :) I think your fundamental understanding of how this messaging library works is off, and I'm trying to correct that.

Your code does NOT work as intended when you're using the one-way client mode, _it's just not giving you an error_. If your code worked, we wouldn't be having this discussion.

The code sample in the answer is the simplest request/reply example I can come up with, I even adapted it to use `Job` and `ReplyMsg`.

Comment: I've added a [request/reply sample](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/RequestReply) to Rebus' samples repository - please check it out and convince yourself that the code can actually run

Comment: Ok, I looked at the sample and it does work, but here are a few things for future reference. 1. That code above absolutely does not work, you left out the EnsureTableIsCreated() part that makes it work, it's present in the sample. 2. The example was inconsistent with the other examples in the database name used. 3. The code I showed absolutely worked when using UseSqlServerInOneWayClientMode, because no reply is expected... continued...

Comment: 4. There was nothing wrong with my code using the reply, all I did to make it work was add a separate producer queue and the code works. I think you were trying to say that, but the way you expressed it was very cryptic to a new user of the Bus, WHICH IS FANTASTIC by the way. So, thanks for building the sample, I would only say that you should use the database name rebus_test instead of just rebus to make it the same as the other samples.. Thanks!

Comment: excellent! thanks for the feedback, and it's a good thing it ended out well :) PS: I've updated the answer with `EnsureTableIsCreated` so that it works

Comment: Agreed! All's well that ends well, lol! Thanks for hanging in there with me!